# Update Combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a Textbox where you can write a Subject into it and press a button to send the new subject into a database. My combobox shows all subjects in the database and you can choose one and delete it. All programmed with Entity Framework. The Combobox is filled with values during Form.Load-Event.

When I write a new entry in the textbox the combobox has to refresh coz I want the possibility to delete the new entry as well.

I tried

`cmb.refresh`,

```
cmb.update
```

both not working, probably because the code to fill the comboboxes is in the form.load event. So i tried to refresh the form with

```
me.update
```

but this is not working too. Any idea how I can update (refill) my combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so take all the code in your `Form.load` event

Put this code into a new method called UpdateCbo.

```
  Private Sub UpdateCbo()
    // your form.load code
  End Sub
```

Then in your form.load event, call this new method.

```
Public Sub FormLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  UpdateCbo()
End Sub
```

Then also if you want the combobox to refresh when you add a new entry, you can either hook `UpdateCbo` up to a button click event or the textchanged event of your combo box.

e.g:

```
Private Sub Cbo_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbo.TextChanged
  UpdateCbo()
End Sub
```

Comment: @ruedi Did my answer not help?

Answer (score 0):

How do you fill and bind values to the combobox? You can take that code out into a separate function "`fillComboBox`", and call that upon filling the textbox.

If you post a code sample I can show you what I mean.